# Keeping the same form on the reload of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two forms on my page and have a button which fade out the current form and brings another one. Basically, those two forms are of login and sign up respectively. A button when clicked toggles between both of them. Here's what happens:

1. Login form is the default current form and I click on the button to change the form to sign up form.
2. I then go click the submit button of the sign up form which reloads the page.
3. Then as usual the login form appears.

Here comes the problem, I want the form which was lastly the current one as to be the current one even after the page reloads.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="content">
    <div id="logo" style="margin-left: 0;"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="sign_up" action="login.php" method="post">
            <table style="margin: 0px auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2em; color: Gray;">Sign Up</span>

                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="required" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" required="required" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="submit_sign_up">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <form id="sign_in" action="login.php" method="post">
            <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2em; color: Gray;">Sign In</span>

                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="required" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In" name="submit_sign_in">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <input id="sign_up_btn" class="btn" type="submit" style=" font-weight:bold; height:40px; width: 292px;" value="Create An Account"></input>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #aaa inset;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sign_in, #sign_up {
    border: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 292px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px #000;
}
#sign_up {
    display: none;
    height: 250px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $sUp = $("#sign_up"),
        $sIn = $("#sign_in");

    $("#content").on('click', "#sign_up_btn", function () {

        $sIn.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sUp.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Already have an account?",
                id: "sign_in_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });

    }).on('click', "#sign_in_btn", function () {

        $sUp.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sIn.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Create An Account",
                id: "sign_up_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: We won't code for you, post an error if you have one, if not, narrow down your code.

Comment: store which form was visible last in a cookie, and then on page load check for the cookie and set the correct form

Comment: There's not even a need for that. Your server-side code obviously knows which form was submitted. Use that information to make appropriate adjustments to the page served after the submission so that the same form appears by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing to do is to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to save the state of the form.  You might want to think about looking for a framework that handles page states if you want to do more of this.

The gollowing sets the value of `lastForm` in `localStorage` in each event handler.  After the handlers are defined, it changes the current form if `localStorage.lastForm` equals `sign_up`.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $sUp = $("#sign_up"),
        $sIn = $("#sign_in");

    $("#content").on('click', "#sign_up_btn", function () {

        $sIn.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sUp.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Already have an account?",
                id: "sign_in_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });
        localStorage.lastForm = 'sign_up';
    }).on('click', "#sign_in_btn", function () {

        $sUp.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sIn.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Create An Account",
                id: "sign_up_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });
        localStorage.lastForm = 'sign_in';
    });

    if (localStorage.lastForm == 'sign_up') {
        $sIn.fadeOut(0);
        $sUp.fadeIn(0);
    }
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EYL8K/)